How can I correctly add chapter headings to lists of tables and figures in a class derived from book.cls using hooks?
I've been trying to help out my graduate students by creating a shared .cls file for university theses and dissertations. I know there are a ton out there, but this is also an interesting exercise for me because I'm using it to learn latex3 programming.
I thought it would be cleaner to demarcate the LoF and LoT for figures and tables in a new chapter. Of course, a short chapter or an appendix might not have tables or figures, so I only want the heading to appear in the LoT/LoF if there is a table or figure. My solution was to use some hooks. I created a boolean for figures and another for tables. When the value is true, then the chapter already has a figure or table. When the value is false, and we encounter a figure or table environment, a hook will add the chapter number to the LoT/LoF as appropriate. This is done using the recent \AddToHook features on the corresponding float.
At every chapter, both booleans are set to false. Because I haven't been able to figure out how to use the new hook mechanism for that, i used \pretocmd from etoolbox.
I want to apologise for not having a MWE of the problem. Basically, in one grad student's dissertation, Figure 2.1 appears in the LoF before the "Chapter 2" marker in the same LoF. I have no idea why, but I suspect that it's the usual suspect (my ignorance).

\bool_new:N \l__nusthesis_table_in_chapter_bool  %% has a table already appeared in this chapter
\bool_new:N \l__nusthesis_figure_in_chapter_bool  %% has a figure already appeared in this chapter


\AddToHook{env/table/before}{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nusthesis_table_in_chapter_bool {%
    }{%
    \bool_set_true:N \l__nusthesis_table_in_chapter_bool
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\chaptertitlename \  \thechapter}{}{}}
      }}

 \AddToHook{env/longtable/before}{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nusthesis_table_in_chapter_bool {%
    }{%
    \bool_set_true:N \l__nusthesis_table_in_chapter_bool
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\chaptertitlename \  \thechapter}{}{}}
    }}
    
\AddToHook{env/figure/before}{
    \bool_if:NTF \l__nusthesis_figure_in_chapter_bool {%
    }{%
    \bool_set_true:N \l__nusthesis_figure_in_chapter_bool
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\chaptertitlename \  \thechapter}{}{}}
  }}


\NewDocumentCommand{\ResetFloatsInChapter}{}{
  \bool_set_false:N \l__nusthesis_table_in_chapter_bool
  \bool_set_false:N \l__nusthesis_figure_in_chapter_bool
}

\pretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \ResetFloatsInChapter{}}{}{}


I provide an example from the PDF of my student's dissertation below. FWIW, the first figure in chapter 2 is on page 29 after the last table in Chapter 2 (on page 28). In addition, chapter 1 has no tables. I have no idea if any of that is relevant, but thought it worth mentioning.


sorry but without MWE it would be only guessing. Perhaps there is some additional grouping somewhere. Add \bool_show:N in various place to check the state of the booleans.

@UlrikeFischer I appreciate that, and I tried to create an MWE, but I've currently only seen it happen in the student's thesis, which I obviously can't use as for the purpose. I'm hoping there's some flaw in the logic or the way I mixed the hooks.

sure you can use the thesis. Copy that into some empty folder, remove all irrelevant text  (as the error is already in chapter 2, you can ignore everything after chapter 2) and packages, replace other text by lipsum and post that as MWE.
